# Creating image in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image

I am trying to creage an image in ASP.
I have tried this code but it does not work:

```
Image img;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img = new Image();
    img.ImageUrl = "~/images/numbersHorizontal.png";
    img.ID = "img";
}
```

Comment: Do you want create an image control dynamically, or generate an image?

Comment: create an image control dynamically

Answer (score 3):

Code to create image looks correct. The only part that is missing is to add newly created image to the page. Try adding this as a last line:

```
this.Controls.Add(img);
```

Comment: @user2320928: Consider accept the answer (using green tick to the left).